# Why do my tears burn?

Tags: eye, pluck-plucking, tear-duct, watery-eyes, blood-shot-eyes

When I cry or tear up, my eyes start burning and get red, causing me to tear up more. It helps when I wash my eyes with warm water. I don't understand, because my eyes aren't dry to start with so there must be some tears there to start with. I'm not wearing contacts or eye shadow or eye liner at the time. This happens when I watch a sad movie or pluck hairs. It's like I'm allergic to my own tears.

No, I'm not going to the doctor and I'm in perfect health.